# Long time exection in update table with join in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization, sql-update

i'm facing a big problem when trying to update a table containing stock data put in join with a table containing product classification. This operation is taking long time for execution.

Table dw_giacenze (having flag_nomatch parameter equal to T) a is put on inner join with dw_key_prod z on ecat_key field.
a contains up to 3 milions records, z 150k records.
It takes more than 2 hours in execution.

Below the update query I'm using.

```
update dw_giacenze 
set cate_ecat_key = z.cate_ecat_key,
        sottocat_ecat_key = z.sottocat_ecat_key,
    marchio_key = z.marchio_key,
    sottocat_bi_key = z.sottocat_bi_key,
    gruppo_bi_key = z.gruppo_bi_key,
    famiglia_bi_key = z.famiglia_bi_key,
    flag_nomatch = NULL
from dw_giacenze a
    inner join dw_key_prod z on
        z.ecat_key = a.ecat_key
where
    a.flag_nomatch = 'T';
```

Can anyone help me in optimizing it?
Thanks in advance!

Enrico

Comment: Show your query plan. Menu "Query", "Display estimated execution plan".

Comment: Does dw_giacenze have many indices that need to be updated? Does the SELECT query with same tables and conditions also take long time to run? Do you have any indices on ecat_key in both tables and is there an index on flag_nomatch?

Comment: Hi David, I performed query execution plan and SQL Server said that /*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery4.sql - 46.51.199.197.EURDB-DEV (EUR-DEV (53))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 96.6899%.
*/

/*
USE [EURDB-DEV]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[dw_giacenze] ([flag_nomatch])
INCLUDE ([ecat_key])
GO
*/

Comment: Have you added the missing index and how did it affect execution time?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest focusing in on a.flag_nomatch = 'T'.

A great way to get a really clear picture of what's going on is to use SQL Server Profiler.  If this shows that your reads equals the number of rows in the table, then that's definitely an issue.  Adding an index on flag_nomatch.

Alternatively, you could separate this out and update things individually (to start with)

```
UPDATE dw_giacenze 
    set sottocat_ecat_key = (SELECT sottocat_ecat_key 
                             FROM dw_key_prod 
                             WHERE dw_key_prod.ecat_key = dw_giacenze.ecat_key)
where
    dw_giacenze.flag_nomatch = 'T';
```

I did notice that the first parameter in your set statement is actually the same parameter in your join.  That means that you are setting it to the same exact value, so you should be able to remove that anyway.